# Pandas Data Frame function application to a specific row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply one function `f1` to rows `['Utah,'Texas']` and `f2` to other rows. I don't want to create separate DF for each function.

Example adjusted from Wes McKinney's Python for Data Analysis:

**MWE:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), 
                  columns=list('bde'), 
                  index=['Utah', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Oregon'])

f1 = lambda x: (x-x.min())/(x.max() - x.min())
f2 = lambda x: (x-x.max())/(x.min() - x.max())
```

I've tried selecting row by label: `frame.loc['Utah'].apply(f1,axis=1)`.

I can feel that it is something very small that I'm missing but...

Comment: Can you show us a minimal working demonstrative code? [ask]

Comment: MWE should work. It is a very short code.

Comment: @Michal It actually didn't, as you used ``Pandas`` and ``Numpy`` (with capitals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a 2d `numpy.array` whose each row is the application of one of the two functions to the dataframe according to the rules you specified for that row:

```
np.where(
    np.array([frame.index.isin(['Utah', 'Texas']) for _ in frame.columns]).T,
    frame.apply(f1, axis=1),
    frame.apply(f2, axis=1))
```

Since you didn't specify the output fully, it's hard to guess what you want to do further.

Comment: As an output I would need to have a new Data Frame with given outputs.

Comment: So check how to create a DataFrame from a numpy.array. It's not that diificult.

Comment: It works ! I think it would be easier for me either to create separate DFs for each function or to transpose `frame` and then `frame[['Utah','Texas']].apply(f1)`